# wp_kses missing two arguments issue

Tags: wordpress, apache, nginx, arguments, wordpress-theming

After migrating to new AWS instance and moving from apache to nginx I have a problem with wp_kses that I didn't have before.

The form submits and all processing goes well, but instead of redirecting to the success page I get an error messages like this:

**Warning: Missing argument 2 for wp_kses(), called in path/to/a/file.php on line 20 and defined in root/folder/public_html/wp-includes/kses.php on line 521**

This is my code for processing form

```
//Template Name: Jobs: Add mini ad form process

if (!wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['ad_mini_add_nonce'], 'submit_add_mini_ad_form' )) :

    echo 'Sorry your nonce didn\'t verify';
    exit;

endif;

    // Checking for secret filed
    if (isset($_POST["secret_field"]) && !empty($_POST["secret_field"])) :

        echo 'Sorry, could not send.';
        exit;

    endif;

        // process form data
        $position_name          = wp_kses($_POST['position_name']);
        $company_name           = wp_kses($_POST['company_name']);
        $location               = wp_kses($_POST['location']);
        $link_for_apply         = wp_kses($_POST['link_for_apply']);
        $website                = wp_kses($_POST['website']);
        $name                   = wp_kses($_POST['name']);
        $email                  = wp_kses($_POST['email']);
        $phone                  = wp_kses($_POST['phone']);


        // Create new add - privately published
        $new_ad = array(
          'post_title'      => $position_name,
          'post_type'       => 'post',
          'post_status'     => 'private',
          'post_author'     => 1001189, //Tanja Mladenovic
        );
        $new_ad_id  = wp_insert_post($new_ad);
        $new_ad_url = get_post_permalink($new_ad_id);
        $next_month         = date( 'Ymd', strtotime('+30 days', time()) );
        // Fill custom fileds
        add_post_meta($new_ad_id, 'company_location', $location);
        add_post_meta($new_ad_id, 'ad_type', 'mini');
        add_post_meta($new_ad_id, 'company_name', $company_name);
        add_post_meta($new_ad_id, 'webiste', $webiste);
        add_post_meta($new_ad_id, 'expire', $next_month);
        add_post_meta($new_ad_id, 'contact_person_name', $name);
        add_post_meta($new_ad_id, 'contact_person_phone', $phone);
        add_post_meta($new_ad_id, 'contact_person_email', $email);
        add_post_meta($new_ad_id, 'type_of_apply', 'link');
        add_post_meta($new_ad_id, 'link_for_apply', $link);
```

I know wp_kses can have two more arguments, but everything worked before without trouble. Official documentations says that wp_kses second argument ***'allowed_html'*** has default value of none (and that is exactly what I want), and third argument ***'allowed_protocols'*** is optional

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I realized what's the problem. It was WordPress update. In this newer version `wp_kses` must have second argument. Im my case, I don't want to allow html, so I added empty array, and it works

So I changed this part:

```
$position_name          = wp_kses($_POST['position_name']);
$company_name           = wp_kses($_POST['company_name']);
$location               = wp_kses($_POST['location']);
$link_for_apply         = wp_kses($_POST['link_for_apply']);
$website                = wp_kses($_POST['website']);
$name                   = wp_kses($_POST['name']);
$email                  = wp_kses($_POST['email']);
$phone                  = wp_kses($_POST['phone']);
```

to this:

```
$position_name          = wp_kses($_POST['position_name'], array());
$company_name           = wp_kses($_POST['company_name'], array());
$location               = wp_kses($_POST['location'], array());
$link_for_apply         = wp_kses($_POST['link_for_apply'], array());
$website                = wp_kses($_POST['website'], array());
$name                   = wp_kses($_POST['name'], array());
$email                  = wp_kses($_POST['email'], array());
$phone                  = wp_kses($_POST['phone'], array());
```